# Should I start learning HTML basics, or go directly into HTML5?

Tags: html, xhtml, css

I am a designer and my only knowledge with programming is ActionScript 3.0. ActionScript is quite different in different versions — ActionScript 3.0 is a lot diffrent than ActionScript 2.0 or ActionScript 1.0, so it’s no good learning 1.0 or 2.0, the best thing is to learn 3.0 and you're good.

I'm wondering if it is the same with HTML?

I want to start learning about XHTML, HTML & HTML5, and CSS3. Should I start learning about the basics of HTML first, would that be usefull to me? Or should I go straight into HTML5?

Please recommend whatever you think would get me started. (Books, great video tutorials, maybe some guy that is good at teaching in video tutorials, advice, tips, anything you consider relevant is welcome.)

Thank you.

Comment: It’s not the same with HTML. Because HTML parsing is implemented in software products made by lots of different companies (rather than one ActionScript interpreter written by Adobe) and relied on by web pages made by billions of authors, features are generally added to the language rather than redesigned. Backwards compatibility rules.

Answer (score 10):

HTML 5 is (essentially) HTML 4 with bits added, so learn "HTML".

5 isn't a rewrite from scratch, and it is still in draft form so large chunks of it are subject to change and have limited browser support.

Comment: Exactly: it's disingenuous to treat HTML and HTML5 as two separate entities. Unlike ActionScript, the HTML spec is constantly evolving and is far more fluid. Having said that, it makes sense to understand the basics (div, span etc) before trying to get your head around the complexities of when a section or an aside will best serve your content.

Comment: ok, can you recommend any tutorials ? how did you guys got started with HTML ?

Answer (score 4):

When you think about html, 4 or 5, you need to primarily see it is a language for describing documents and the data they contain. At its core, html is just that. It is gaining new capabilities, but it's still a markup language for documents. People are trying to look at it as a robust programming language, but even the new dynamic features require javascript to assist its functionality. Don't be tricked into thinking html5 is all that different from html4 - They still do the same things, for the most part.

The key to writing good, useful html (Regardless of the version) is proper use of semantics and clean/efficient code authoring practices. If you're using the proper tags and writing very clean code, you're already doing better than some 'professionals' I work with. This is a big deal.

When you look at a document, you can break it down into parts. There are doctypes, meta data, linked resources, media objects (images, embedded objects), text based data (tabular, paragraphs, headings, quotes, lists, etc), forms, frames, and the elements that hold all of this together, with or without styles.

That is essentially the foundation of an html document. You can output it with php or ruby or whatever you like, but a proper document will always contain some (Or occasionally all) of these things. An ideal document will contain these things in the correct places (clean, consistent coding) to serve the purpose they are intended for (semantics).

What html5 introduces are additional elements to satisfy semantic requirements as well as useful, dynamic elements that align well with growing requirements based on how people use and develop websites. For example, there's canvas, a scriptable rectangular element for presenting visual information. Then there is local storage - the ability to save key pair style data into a user's web client database for later access, which would be extremely useful for saving changes made to contenteditable elements (Another html5 feature) on a site, perhaps, if you knew the same client would always be used. There's quite a bit more, but I guess you get the picture.

The new html5 features are extraneous to writing 'good html'. They're useful, but you can learn to write great html without them. In fact, that's exactly what I've been doing for the last ten years before html5 appeared. I recommend starting with the basics - Learn about semantics, what they mean, why we'd use them, and even include new html5 tags (Outside of canvas - Canvas is a useful element, but using it is not necessarily using html). Learn about browser support for elements, then learn to link resources in the head, such as stylesheets and javascript. Eventually, you'll have a good feel for basic html, and you'll start wanting to use more advanced techniques.

For now, if you aren't a master of new html5 features, you aren't missing out. There's some cool stuff, sure, but the spec may still change and you can spend this valuable time learning the things that *won't* change - The fundamental things that make html coders genuinely useful.

edit: As for resources, check out these sites:

**Generally useful resources**

[Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/) - Good blog, browser compatibility tables

[html dog](http://www.htmldog.com/) - Very basic, would start you off well

**HTML5 Semantics and other information**

[HTML5 Doctor](http://html5doctor.com/) - Easy reading; To learn a bit about new html5 tags, but mostly, their semantic intention (This is important)

[A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/semanticsinhtml5) - A good look at semantics, again.

[Dive into html5](http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/) - For when you just feel like doing some reading

Comment: When did HTML Goodies get a great reputation? I picked up a copy of the dead tree edition of JavaScript Goodies (because it was 50p) as a test once, other web developers reacted to it in as if they were vampires and it was a bible. Having just skimmed a few articles on the site, it doesn't appear to have improved much since I last looked at it.

Comment: I'll remove that reference. It's certainly well spoken of across the internet, but that doesn't necessarily mean the people speaking know what they're talking about. I took a look, and it seems *alright*, but a little lacking in some regards. For example, calling anchors 'href tags'. Good intentions, poor execution I suppose. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 is just the same old HTML but updated to match today's internet. There is no reason (that I can see) to learn the same language but with outdated information. It will only serve to confuse you - I suggest you instead focus on HTML5 and CSS (XHTML is pretty much HTML4 with some stricter rules) and move on from there to whatever interest you most.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please reccomend a good video tutorial to get me started, directly with HTML5 and or an introduction ? I like video cause I can actually hear while I write the code myself and look at the guy and check that his code is working, see what he is using to write the code(for example for ActionScript I use FlashDevelop, it has great autocomplete suggestion, colors the whole thing nicely(vars are blue, functions are green etc) ... something like that for HTML and CSS? what are the best tools ? [maybe I should add parts of this comment in the question...hmz] thxAgain

Comment: I believe there are some free, open-source solutions, but I didn't check them out so I can't recommend. I can, however recommend Lynda.com which is proprietary, and you have to pay to view the videos, but the videos are clear, to the point (mostly) and professional (from what I've seen) so you might want to check them out.

Comment: One big caution I'd give you about HTML5 -- be aware what browsers you're targeting w/ the website or web application you're creating.  While HTML5/CSS3 are gaining more widespread support, using it in older desktop browsers such as IE7/8 isn't well supported.  If your'e primarily targeting specific mobile browsers it has better support.

If you want to know what HTML5 features are supported by what browsers, I highly recommend taking a look at http://caniuse.com/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should start with the foundation, HTML, before learning about the things that depend on HTML

Comment: To be fair HTML itself only really has a few tags with a handful of attributes (styles not included, that's part of CSS). HTML5 wouldn't be that bad of a start.

Comment: @Blindy: very true, although I don’t know of any HTML5 learning resources that don’t assume you already know HTML.

Comment: The downside of starting straight out w/ HTML5 is it may leave a new designer or web developer unaware of the limitations on using new aspects of HTML5 or CSS3 that aren't well supported on older browsers.  Then again, HTML4 has its own quirks and oddities.